# I added a CSS accordion menu to my squareqpace site, but it seems to be extending beyond the edge of the site

Tags: html, css, checkbox, accordion, squarespace

I added some code blocks to my squarespace site in order to have an accordion style menu for my faq page. [Here](https://geoffgraham.me/css-only-accordion-using-the-checkbox-hack/#comment-962) is my source for the code. However, for some reason the code elements seem to have extended beyond the right edge of the page, so a scroll bar gets added, but it just scrolls into a blank section to the right of the content (see pic attached). I've tried changing up the margins, padding, and width on all of the CSS elements, but I can't get the accordion to fit properly on the screen. Can anyone please help me?? Here is the code that I'm using...

```css
.accordion {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion__wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 4px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion__header,
.accordion__item {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion__header {
  background: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion__item {
  background: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion__item:last-of-type {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.accordion__item span {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.accordion__item input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.accordion__item input[type=checkbox]:checked~div.panel {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}

.accordion__item input[type=checkbox]:checked~span {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <ul class="accordion__wrapper">
  
    <li class="accordion__header">
      <h2>Subscription FAQ</h2>
    </li>
    <!-- accordion__header -->

    <li class="accordion__item">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <h4>+ Question 1</h4>
      <div class="panel">
        <p4>Answer to question 1</p4>
      </div>
      <!-- panel -->
    </li>
    <!-- accordion__item -->

    <li class="accordion__item">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <h4>+ Question 2</h4>
      <div class="panel">
        <p4>Answer to question 2</p4>
      </div>
      <!-- panel -->
    </li>
    <!-- accordion__item -->

    <li class="accordion__item">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <h4>+ Question 3</h4>
      <div class="panel">
        <p4>Answer to question 3</p4>
      </div>
      <!-- panel -->
    </li>
    <!-- accordion__item -->
  </ul>
  <!-- accordion__wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- accordion -->
```

[scrollbar appears at the bottom of page, but scrolls into an empty section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54AqY.png)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please use the SO-Code-Snippet (ctrl + m) the next time you insert your code. The code snippet can be parsed/run so that we can actually see what the code is doing. I edited your question to use the code snippet.

Comment: dont sue width `100%` use `100vw` instead. Also dont use `translate` to cenetr elements. Use the correct tools (`margin: 0 auto;`, ´text-align: center` or `flexbox`). Float shouldnt be used for styling purpose either. It was never intented for that purpose just for floating images within a text paragraph. This "mis-use" is not necessary since we got flexbox and css-grid for a couple of years already.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the absolute position without setting the left property, that property has a default value of 'auto'.

According to
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp:

"auto = auto Lets the browser calculate the left edge position. This is default"

If you set the left property for this element with the value '0' it will be positioned from the edge of the page on the left side.

```css
.accordion__item input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;  /* add this line */
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

looking over the CSS I found removing the width from the input class, fixes this issue :D.

```
.accordion__item input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    **width: 100%;** <--- remove this :D 
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Thanks, Dan